# using arraylist to create to inputs

Tags: java, arraylist

I think I have got myself into a bit of muddle. I had teacher and student below in two separate `addMember` sections. For the purpose of what I am doing they have to in one section but when someone wants to add either student or teacher they need to be able to be added separately (so one call which will give the option of adding either). But my knowledge of arrayLists is not very good and as you can see isn't working very well. Any help be much needed and appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;



public class Committee {

    private String name;

    private List<Object> members;

    public Committee(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
        members = new ArrayList<Object>();
        List list = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void addMember(Student student, Teacher teacher) 
    {
        List members1 = new ArrayList();
        members1.add(student);
        System.out.println(members1);
        List members2 = new ArrayList();
        members2.add(teacher);
        System.out.println(members2);
    }

    public void printMembership() 
    {
        System.out.println("Membership of the " + name + " Committee ");
        Iterator<Object> it = members.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) 
        {
            Object member = it.next();
            System.out.println(members);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, right now your `addMember` method doesn't actually put anything into `members`.  I don't know whether you want two lists (one for students and one for teachers), or just one list containing all of them.

Comment: one list, that allows either both or one to be added not have both added at the same time.

Comment: Its not quite clear which is the `addMember` method's actual purpose. If you could provide some more details or at least the basic structure you want to implement. Looks like you have been requested to put a `List` inside a `List` or a simple abstract / generic subclass

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, so I will write two solutions:

1. Situation where you want to have one list

   ```
   interface Member {...}
   class Student implements Member {...}
   class Teacher implements Member {...}

   public class Comittee {
       private list<Member> members;

       public void addMember(Member member) {
           members.add(member);
       }

       public void printMembership() {
           members.forEach(System.out::println);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Situation where you want to have two lists

   ```
   interface Member ...
   class Student implements Member ...
   class Teacher implements Member ...

   public class Comittee {
       private list<Teacher> teachers;
       private list<Student> students;

       public void addMember(Student student, Teacher teacher) {
           students.add(student);
           teachers.add(teacher);
       }

       public void printMembership() {
           getAllMembers().forEach(System.out::println);
       }

       private void getAllMembers(): List<Member> {
           List<Member> allMembers = ArrayList<>(students.size() + teachers.size());
           allMembers.addAll(teachers);
           allMembers.addAll(students);
           return allMembers;
       }
   }
   ```